# JMS Queue : Multiple Threads to read

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a java program that puts down into the queue on the other side of the queue, i do have 10-15 consumers; any ONE of which should read the message and process it. If any of the 10-15 consumers get free they pick up the next message from the queue.

Basically, a Consumer can pickup the message from the queue whenever it is free, and only one consumer must pick it up. (without any synchronization blocks or so).

 Also on the sender's end can i pause sending the messages into the queue if the queue sizes becomes full(or reaches a certain threshold)?

I am really new to the JMS API. Apologies if this is a newbie question .

Thanks!!

Comment: what's your question? yes, you can stop sending messages into the queue if you feel like it.

Comment: @eis I thought my question was clear. If it is not.. I have to Send messages into a queue and i have 20 threads running as consumers, who can pick up the data from the queue(once they are free). so when each thread gets free it goes to the queue checks if the data is there it picks up and so on.. is this doable?  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: ok, you left the "is this doable" part out, so it wasn't clear that was the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to Send messages into a queue and i have 20 threads running as
>   consumers, who can pick up the data from the queue(once they are
>   free). so when each thread gets free it goes to the queue checks if
>   the data is there it picks up and so on.. is this doable?

Yes, it's doable - that's the standard process of doing it with JMS queues. Another alternative would be topics, but with topics, every listener would have to process the same message, not just one, so queues are what you want. Although usually you don't have threads as consumers (I'm not even sure what that means), but message-driven beans. You might consider using them. MDBs run in their own thread anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the patience and answer this :) . I am still not able to get this. See, i have to have 10 Consumers listening to the same queue/topic, and ONLY one must pick up the message(whenever a consumer is free or polls the queue for the message). Can you provide me any links? where i can read about it and save ur time. - Thanks again!

Comment: @user1613403 I think I answered this already. That's the standard process of doing it with JMS queues. Topics don't support that.

Comment: Alright i read about it, and i think this is the way it can be done..However, there is no way to control the Number of messages Staying the queue. The Queue cannot be dimensioned according to the number of messages

Comment: @user1613403 sure there is, see [this example of weblogic configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/ConsoleHelp/domain_jmsqueue_config_thresholds.html) and [this for OpenMQ](http://www.coderanch.com/t/471077/java/Maximum-number-messages-Queue-OpenMQ). also, for all implementations, you can check the amount of messages in the queue at any given time and act accordingly

Comment: Oh my bad, i am using ActiveMQ, not sure how to handle it there.. also is there any way..to notify my consumers to shut them down? or the message will not be put on queue anymore? like the input data is finished or so?

Comment: why would consumers be shutting down?

Comment: I think you should try out some book on the basics of JMS. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdr.html) and [this](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0735712557/samplechapter/0735712557c.pdf) might help you get started.